# How to read Employee Name from comma separated Employee IDs in Codeigniter Controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a user_access table like below:

| module_id | user_id |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | 1,2,3 |
| 102 | 1,3 |

I have fetched the data from database to datatable with codeigniter controller. The controller looks like below:

`public function user_access_list(){

```
    $draw = intval($this->input->get("draw"));
    $start = intval($this->input->get("start"));
    $length = intval($this->input->get("length"));

    $fetch = $this->Erp_model->get_user_access_settings();
    $data = array();

    foreach($fetch->result() as $r) {
        
        $users = explode(',',$r->user_id);
        foreach($users as $user) {
            $read = $this->Erp_model->read_user_info($user);
            $name = $read[0]->first_name.' '.$read[0]->last_name;
        }

        $data[] = array(
            $combhr,
            $r->module_id,
            $name
        );
    }
    $output = array(
        "draw" => $draw,
        "recordsTotal" => $fetch->num_rows(),
        "recordsFiltered" => $fetch->num_rows(),
        "data" => $data
    );
    echo json_encode($output);
    exit();
}`
```

In the frontend I can see single employee name while there are couple of names. Frontend view like:

| Module ID | Employees |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | A |
| 102 | B |

But I wanted to achieve like this:

| Module ID | Employees |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | A, B, C |
| 102 | A, C |

How can I do this with Codeigniter Controller?

Comment: read up on database normalization: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization, tomorrow you want to make a query to find "1" and you don't because it could be any like: "101", "11", "10" etc....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your current database setup and code, the easiest solution is to use an array to store the names for each row (`$names = [];`), then implode the names with a comma when adding them to the `$data` array:

```
public function user_access_list(){

    $draw = intval($this->input->get("draw"));
    $start = intval($this->input->get("start"));
    $length = intval($this->input->get("length"));

    $fetch = $this->Erp_model->get_user_access_settings();
    $data = array();

    foreach($fetch->result() as $r) {
        
        $names = [];
        $users = explode(',',$r->user_id);
        foreach($users as $user) {
            $read = $this->Erp_model->read_user_info($user);
            $names[] = $read[0]->first_name.' '.$read[0]->last_name;
        }

        $data[] = array(
            $combhr,
            $r->module_id,
            implode(',', $names)
        );
    }
    $output = array(
        "draw" => $draw,
        "recordsTotal" => $fetch->num_rows(),
        "recordsFiltered" => $fetch->num_rows(),
        "data" => $data
    );
    echo json_encode($output);
    exit();
}
```

A better solution would be to normalize your database, so that your `user_access` table looks like this (there can only be a single id in the `user_id` column and therefore the `module_id` has to be repeated for every user):

| module_id | user_id |
| --- | --- |
| 101 | 1 |
| 101 | 2 |
| 101 | 3 |
| 102 | 1 |
| 102 | 3 |

Then you can join this `user_access` table to the `users` table, `group by` `module_id` and use `group_concat` to get the names separated with a comma. This way you'll be able to get all of your data in one query (the separate queries to get the names are no longer neccessary), so it'll be faster.